# Javascript Web-Components - add subitems

Tags: javascript, web-component

```js
class Table extends HTMLElement {
  // attributes
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = 'undefined';
    this.icon = 'bi-patch-question';
  }

  // component attributes
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['name', 'icon', 'properties'];
  }

  // attribute change
  attributeChangedCallback(property, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (oldValue == newValue) return;
    this[ property ] = newValue;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

    shadow.innerHTML = `
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <div class="card">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
          <caption>${this.name}<i class="bi ${this.icon}"></i></caption>
      </tr>
      <!-- here should be the em-tds -->
    </table></div>
    
    <style>
    .card {
      border: 1px solid lightgray;
      border-radius: 15px;
      margin: 10px 0;
      padding: 15px;
    }
  
    table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    tr {
      border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
    }

    tr:first-child {
      border: none;
    }

    td {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 7px;
      font-size: 18px;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    caption {
        position: relative;
        font-family: ExtraBold;
        padding: 7px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: 18px;
        text-decoration: 2px underline;
    }

    caption i {
      position: absolute;
      right: 6px;
      font-size: 22px;
    }
    </style>
    `
  }
}

class TableTds extends HTMLElement {
  // attributes
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = 'undefined';
    this.value = 'undefined';
  }

  // component attributes
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ['name', 'value'];
  }

  // attribute change
  attributeChangedCallback(property, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (oldValue == newValue) return;
    this[ property ] = newValue;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

    shadow.innerHTML = `
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <td>${this.name}</td>
    <td>${this.value}></td>
    `
  }
}




customElements.define('em-table', Table);
customElements.define('em-td', TableTds);
```

```html
<em-table name="test">
  <em-td name="test" value="10"></em-td>
  <em-td name="test" value="10"></em-td>
</em-table>
```

I'm working on new web-components for my plattform and ran in some kind of issue. Creating web-components works fine for me but I wanted to create sub-components inside the tags of a web-component. Obviously that has not worked, because the component is protected from everything else...

In my case its about a table web-component, in which I would like to have the html-tds as subcomponents, to later use them properly.

I've tried to use slots but that has not worked...

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be an answer but what if instead of shadow.innerHTML = ... in the Table class, you do shadow.innerHTML = \`...table,caption,tr...\` + shadow.innerHTML. That way you preserve the HTML children, if it works, let me know so that I post as answer instead. But hope you understand ?

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately. Everything inside the <em-table>-tags is not showing/gets removed

Comment: what about first assigning its contents to another variable before reassigning, because the contents of custom components don't get discarded, except if we are not accessing the contents properly, wait let me get back to you

Comment: what about shadow.host.innerHTML, because I've been checking MDN docs, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/host here.

Comment: Please use the [ <> ] button in the StackOverflow editor to create an executable SO snippet. You will get more and better answers when we can easily edit your code.

Comment: You have a multitude of problems. Bootstrap icons won't work; name/value properties don't change HTML (you have to write your onw Reactivity when not using a BaseClass that does it for you); shadowRoot can be attached in the constructor (because connectedCallback can run multiple times) and probably more. Tackle them one by one with smaller/easier code.

Comment: The problems are just in this demo version :) I cutted parts that are not so important for this specific version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started, you need to add more yourself.

Main point is **not** to wrap Everything in a shadowDOM,
let your `em-td` find their "table", without having to pierce **UP** through a shadowroot boundary
with:

```js
    connectedCallback() {
      this.closest("em-table")
          .shadowRoot
          .querySelector("table")
          .append(this.tr);
    }
```

###### Working snippet:

Note: using a ***declarative* shadowDOM** `<template shadowroot="open">` for `em-table` here.
You can move it all to its `constructor` if you don't want to start from SSR/HTML

```html
<em-table name="test">
  <template shadowroot="open">
    <div class="card">
      <table class="table">
        <caption></caption>
      </table>
    </div>
    <style>
      tr{background:pink}
    </style>
  </template>
  <em-td name="test1" value="10"></em-td>
  <em-td name="test2" value="20"></em-td>
</em-table>
<script>
  customElements.define('em-table', class extends HTMLElement {
    caption(name, icon) {
      let html = `${name}<i class="bi ${icon}"></i>`;
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector("caption").innerHTML = html;
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.caption('caption', 'bi-patch-question');
    }
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ['name', 'icon', 'properties'];
    }
    attributeChangedCallback(property, oldValue, newValue) {
      if (oldValue == newValue) return;
      this[property] = newValue;
    }
  });
  customElements.define('em-td', class extends HTMLElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ['name', 'value'];
    }
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.tr = document.createElement("tr");
      this._name = document.createElement("td");
      this._value = document.createElement("td");
      this.tr.append(this._name, this._value);
    }
    attributeChangedCallback(property, oldValue, newValue) {
      if (oldValue == newValue) return;
      this[property] = newValue;
    }
    set name(v) {
      this._name.innerText = v;
    }
    set value(v) {
      this._value.innerText = v;
    }
    connectedCallback() {
      this.closest("em-table")
          .shadowRoot.querySelector("table")
          .append(this.tr);
    }
  });
</script>
```

##### And be aware:

From the `<TR>` documentation on MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr

> ##### Permitted parents
>
> `<table>` (only if the table has no child `<tbody>` element, and even
> then only after any `<caption>`, `<colgroup>`, and `<thead>`
> elements); otherwise, the parent must be `<thead>`, `<tbody>` or
> `<tfoot>`

So

```html
<em-table>
  <tr>
```

is **not** valid HTML